# rejectValue and use in jsp. spring3 mvc; jsp;

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

My application has a register page with compulsory check boxes. If the form is submitted without the check boxes being ticked, I want an error message shown when trying to submit the form.

In my controller, I have:

```
 if(req.getParameter("tcCheck")==null)
    result.rejectValue("tcCheck","Check.tc", "Need to accept terms and conditions");
```

my jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" method="post">
   ...
   <form:errors path=tcCheck/>
   ...
</form:form>
```

At runtime, I get this error:

> Error 500: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'tcCheck' of bean class
>   [com.domgen.recupl.domain.User]: Bean property 'tcCheck' is not
>   readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the
>   getter match the parameter type of the setter?

The User domain object does not have tcCheck as one of its instance variables and of course it should not go in the User bean.

I am wondering how I can display my error message without editing the User bean?
Thanks.

A

Answer (score 0):

How about using errors.rejectValue ? See [here](http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2009/05/21/Spring-MVC) for a sample .

Answer (score 0):

In your controller : use addError method

```
if(req.getParameter("tcCheck")==null)
    result.addError(new ObjectError("tcCheck", "error message"));
```

In your jsp: use element attribute instead of path

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" method="post">
  ...
  <form:errors element="tcCheck"/>
  ...
</form:form>
```

Helps!?

Comment: Tried doing this. `<form:errors element="some text"/>` seems to yield the same result as `<form:errors path="*"/>` ie, all the errors are shown in one place as opposed to being separatable. I have more than one bit of errors and with the solution given, all the errors are appearing even though I just want the tcCheck error not to appear.

Answer (score 0):

To use the form errors like that, you must have a getter on your form backing object that matches the form field. so if you want to use

```
<form:errors path="tcCheck"/>
```

you must have a method getTcCheck() on your user object, or a sub-object of your user object.  i.e.

```
<form:errors path="subObject.tcCheck"/>
```

in which case you would use rejectValue("subObject.tcCheck", ...